# Как нарисовать такой значок с помощью fabric.js

Tags: svg, canvas, fabricjs, svg-animation, inkscape

Вот такое надо нарисовать:

[image: значок]

Интересно, как нарисовать полукруги с помощью кривых Безье? Потому что простые полукруги не совсем подходят, так как надо рисовать стрелочки.

Comment: два ответа подготовил для вас. В первом ответе просто подробно объяснил, как можно нарисовать вашу картинку. Второй ответ - анимация этой картинки. Если заинтересует могу дать более подробные объяснения

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Лучше всего рисовать такие вещи в векторном редакторе.

Взял вашу картинку за образец и загрузил её `в Inkscape`  с помощью небольшого файла SVG.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Для чего так делается?*

Чтобы точно нарисовать `path`, привязанный к картинке-образцу.

`width="125"` и  `height="137"` и  `viewBox="0 0 125 137"` выставляются в соответствии с габаритным размерам картинки.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="125" height="137" viewBox="0 0 125 137" >   
 
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRq8G.png" width="125" height="137" />
 
</svg>
```

### Работа с векторным редактором

Весь контур обводить не надо. Будем рисовать среднюю линию, а её ширину выставим потом вручную `stroke-width="5"`

1. С помощью инструмента - `Рисовать кривые Безье` наносите узловые точки
2. Инструментом - `Редактировать узлы контура или рычаги узлов` делаете точки активными (цветными)
3. Далее выбираете - `Сделать узлы автоматически сглаженными` и перемещая рычаги узловых точек добиваемся нужной формы кривой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраняем файл в формате SVG

При сохранении выбирайте `Сохранить как` / выбирайте во второй строчке `inkscape SVG` и в выпадающем списке - `Оптимизированный svg`

**В принципе всё готово**

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="20%" height="20%" viewBox="0 0 125 137">
<style>
.s0{
 fill:none;
 stroke:#365A9E;
}

</style>  
  <g stroke-width="4">
  <path id="curve" d="m50.7 28.8c9.1-7.7 18.6-10.3 28.3-4.3 4.6 2.9 8.7 8.3 10.5 12.2 2.7 5.9 1.6 12.6-1.2 17.4-5.6 9.9-11.5 11.5-20.9 14.1-4.6 1.3-9.4 2-13.6 4.2-3.5 1.8-6.9 4.2-9.2 7.4-2.4 3.2-4.1 7.1-4.5 11.1-0.4 3.9 0.2 8 1.8 11.5 3.3 5.2 8.5 10.1 14 11.9 3.9 1.2 8.4 1.9 12.3 0.8 3.2-0.9 7.8-3.9 7.8-3.9" class="s0"/>
  <path id="left_Line" d="M37.7 71.7 2.9 72" stroke-linecap="round" class="s0"/>
  <path id="right_Line" d="M92.9 72H123.1" stroke-linecap="round" class="s0"/>
  <path id="top_Tri" d="m42.7 19.4 6.7 8.2 6.7 4.9 6.1 3.2-24.9 8.8z" stroke-linejoin="round" class="s0"/>
  <path id="bottom_Tri" d="m89.5 94-23.9 8.6 4 3.1 5.7 4.2 3.8 4.2 2.9 4.1 1.4 1.2z" stroke-linejoin="round" class="s0"/>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

### Примеры анимации лого

Для анимации линий необходимо **точно узнать** их максимальные длины.

Для этого у меня есть простенькая утилита расчета длины любого патча:

Ниже код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
 <div>
 <input  type="button" value="Total"  onclick="TotalLength()"/>
 </div>  
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" > 
   
      <!-- Скопируйте сюда значение атрибута "d" вашего path -->

         <path id="check" fill= "none" stroke ="grey" stroke-width ="1" 
                
      d="m50.7 28.8c9.1-7.7 18.6-10.3 28.3-4.3 4.6 2.9 8.7 8.3 10.5 12.2 2.7 5.9 1.6 12.6-1.2 17.4-5.6 9.9-11.5 11.5-20.9 14.1-4.6 1.3-9.4 2-13.6 4.2-3.5 1.8-6.9 4.2-9.2 7.4-2.4 3.2-4.1 7.1-4.5 11.1-0.4 3.9 0.2 8 1.8 11.5 3.3 5.2 8.5 10.1 14 11.9 3.9 1.2 8.4 1.9 12.3 0.8 3.2-0.9 7.8-3.9 7.8-3.9" >
    
   </path>
</svg> 
   <script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Длина пути - " + len);
        };
  </script>
```

Кривая линия `id="curve"` -`182px`

Каждый треугольник `id="top_Tri"` -`78px`

Каждая прямая линия - id=`right_Line` - `35px`

Анимировать будем с помощью изменения атрибутов `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset`

**1. Одновременная анимация всех линий**

Реализуется условием одновременного запуска `begin="svg1.click"`

```html
<div class="container" >
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="40%" height="40%" viewBox="0 0 125 137">
<style>
.s0{
 fill:none;
 stroke:#365A9E;
}

</style>     
  <!-- Это серая трасса направления анимации. При необходимости её можно удалить. Для этого удаляется вся первая группа <g>... </g> -->
  
   <g stroke-width="4" stroke="#dedede" fill="none">
  <path id="curve" d="m50.7 28.8c9.1-7.7 18.6-10.3 28.3-4.3 4.6 2.9 8.7 8.3 10.5 12.2 2.7 5.9 1.6 12.6-1.2 17.4-5.6 9.9-11.5 11.5-20.9 14.1-4.6 1.3-9.4 2-13.6 4.2-3.5 1.8-6.9 4.2-9.2 7.4-2.4 3.2-4.1 7.1-4.5 11.1-0.4 3.9 0.2 8 1.8 11.5 3.3 5.2 8.5 10.1 14 11.9 3.9 1.2 8.4 1.9 12.3 0.8 3.2-0.9 7.8-3.9 7.8-3.9"/>
  <path  d="M37.7 71.7 2.9 72" stroke-linecap="round" />
  <path  d="M92.9 72H123.1" stroke-linecap="round" />
  <path  d="m42.7 19.4 6.7 8.2 6.7 4.9 6.1 3.2-24.9 8.8z" stroke-linejoin="round" />
  <path  d="m89.5 94-23.9 8.6 4 3.1 5.7 4.2 3.8 4.2 2.9 4.1 1.4 1.2z" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  </g> 
  
  
  <g stroke-width="4">
  <path id="curve" class="s0"  stroke-dasharray="0 91 0 91"
      d="m50.7 28.8c9.1-7.7 18.6-10.3 28.3-4.3 4.6 2.9 8.7 8.3 10.5 12.2 2.7 5.9 1.6 12.6-1.2 17.4-5.6   9.9-11.5 11.5-20.9 14.1-4.6 1.3-9.4 2-13.6 4.2-3.5 1.8-6.9 4.2-9.2 7.4-2.4 3.2-4.1 7.1-4.5 11.1-0.4 3.9 0.2 8 1.8 11.5 3.3  5.2 8.5 10.1 14 11.9 3.9 1.2 8.4 1.9 12.3 0.8 3.2-0.9 7.8-3.9 7.8-3.9" > 
  
      <animate
     id="an_curve"
  attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
  from="0 91 0 91"
  to="0 0 182 0"
  begin="svg1.click"
  dur="2s"
  fill="freeze" /> 
   </path>
  <path id="top_Tri" stroke-dasharray="0 78 0 78" stroke-dashoffset="26"
        d="m42.7 19.4 6.7 8.2 6.7 4.9 6.1 3.2-24.9 8.8z" stroke-linejoin="round" class="s0">
       <animate
      id="an_top_Tri"
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   from="0 39 0 39"
   to="0 0 78 0"
   begin="svg1.click"
   dur="2s"
   fill="freeze" />
  </path>
  <path id="bottom_Tri"  stroke-dasharray="0 78 0 78" stroke-dashoffset="0"
         d="m89.5 94-23.9 8.6 4 3.1 5.7 4.2 3.8 4.2 2.9 4.1 1.4 1.2z" stroke-linejoin="round" class="s0">
        <animate
      id="an_bottom_Tri"
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   from="0 39 0 39"
   to="0 0 78 0"
   begin="svg1.click"
   dur="2s"
   fill="freeze" />
  </path>
 <path id="left_Line"  stroke-dasharray="35" stroke-dashoffset="35"
       d="M37.7 71.7 2.9 72" stroke-linecap="round" class="s0">
       <animate
      id="an_left_Line"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   from="35"
   to="0"
   begin="svg1.click"
   dur="2s"
   fill="freeze" />
  </path>

 <path id="right_Line" stroke-dasharray="35" stroke-dashoffset="35"
         d="M92.9 72H123.1" stroke-linecap="round" class="s0"> 
  <animate
      id="an_left_Line"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   from="35"
   to="0"
   begin="svg1.click"
   dur="2s"
   fill="freeze" /> 
  
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

**2. Последовательная анимация линий**

Реализуется последовательной цепочкой команд запуска анимаций

`begin="svg1.click"`  - запуск рисования кривой

begin="an_curve.end" - запуск рисования треугольников.
 Другими словами можно сказать, что запуск анимации треугольников начнется после окончания рисования кривой.

***Начало анимации в снипете после клика***

```html
 <div class="container" >
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="40%" height="40%" viewBox="0 0 125 137">
<style>
.s0{
 fill:none;
 stroke:#365A9E;
}

</style>     

   <g stroke-width="4" stroke="#dedede" fill="none">
  <path id="curve" d="m50.7 28.8c9.1-7.7 18.6-10.3 28.3-4.3 4.6 2.9 8.7 8.3 10.5 12.2 2.7 5.9 1.6 12.6-1.2 17.4-5.6 9.9-11.5 11.5-20.9 14.1-4.6 1.3-9.4 2-13.6 4.2-3.5 1.8-6.9 4.2-9.2 7.4-2.4 3.2-4.1 7.1-4.5 11.1-0.4 3.9 0.2 8 1.8 11.5 3.3 5.2 8.5 10.1 14 11.9 3.9 1.2 8.4 1.9 12.3 0.8 3.2-0.9 7.8-3.9 7.8-3.9"/>
  <path  d="M37.7 71.7 2.9 72" stroke-linecap="round" />
  <path  d="M92.9 72H123.1" stroke-linecap="round" />
  <path  d="m42.7 19.4 6.7 8.2 6.7 4.9 6.1 3.2-24.9 8.8z" stroke-linejoin="round" />
  <path  d="m89.5 94-23.9 8.6 4 3.1 5.7 4.2 3.8 4.2 2.9 4.1 1.4 1.2z" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  </g>
  <g stroke-width="4">
  <path id="curve" class="s0"  stroke-dasharray="0 91 0 91"
      d="m50.7 28.8c9.1-7.7 18.6-10.3 28.3-4.3 4.6 2.9 8.7 8.3 10.5 12.2 2.7 5.9 1.6 12.6-1.2 17.4-5.6   9.9-11.5 11.5-20.9 14.1-4.6 1.3-9.4 2-13.6 4.2-3.5 1.8-6.9 4.2-9.2 7.4-2.4 3.2-4.1 7.1-4.5 11.1-0.4 3.9 0.2 8 1.8 11.5 3.3  5.2 8.5 10.1 14 11.9 3.9 1.2 8.4 1.9 12.3 0.8 3.2-0.9 7.8-3.9 7.8-3.9" > 
  
      <animate
     id="an_curve"
  attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
  from="0 91 0 91"
  to="0 0 182 0"
  begin="svg1.click"
  dur="1s"
  fill="freeze" /> 
   </path>
  <path id="top_Tri" stroke-dasharray="0 78 0 78" stroke-dashoffset="26"
        d="m42.7 19.4 6.7 8.2 6.7 4.9 6.1 3.2-24.9 8.8z" stroke-linejoin="round" class="s0">
       <animate
      id="an_top_Tri"
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   from="0 39 0 39"
   to="0 0 78 0"
   begin="an_curve.end"
   dur="0.8s"
   fill="freeze" />
  </path>
  <path id="bottom_Tri"  stroke-dasharray="0 78 0 78" stroke-dashoffset="0"
         d="m89.5 94-23.9 8.6 4 3.1 5.7 4.2 3.8 4.2 2.9 4.1 1.4 1.2z" stroke-linejoin="round" class="s0">
        <animate
      id="an_bottom_Tri"
   attributeName="stroke-dasharray"
   from="0 39 0 39"
   to="0 0 78 0"
   begin="an_curve.end"
   dur="0.8s"
   fill="freeze" />
  </path>
 <path id="left_Line"  stroke-dasharray="35" stroke-dashoffset="35"
       d="M37.7 71.7 2.9 72" stroke-linecap="round" class="s0">
       <animate
      id="an_left_Line"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   from="35"
   to="0"
   begin="an_bottom_Tri.end"
   dur="0.5s"
   fill="freeze" />
  </path>

 <path id="right_Line" stroke-dasharray="35" stroke-dashoffset="35"
         d="M92.9 72H123.1" stroke-linecap="round" class="s0"> 
  <animate
      id="an_left_Line"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   from="35"
   to="0"
   begin="an_bottom_Tri.end"
   dur="0.5s"
   fill="freeze" /> 
  
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Ого, очень интересная реализация, принцип как я понял, такой же как было указано пару постов назад. Кстати, как попался данный пост, сразу же подумал - Александр по-любому реализует :)

Comment: @L.F.C. Точно! Анимация из средней точки

Comment: Вот так всегда. Как в той песне из мультика: "Хорошими делами..., прославится нельзя.., ну и т.д." А я плюс поставил Анастасии за вопрос. Вопрос хороший - ответы тоже. Скорее всего не ставит Анастасия галочки )))

Answer (score 2):

Это без fabric.js просто canvas

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

ctx.save();
ctx.transform(0.881373, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.882991, 14.472024, 30.008880);

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.transform(-0.698524, 0.715587, 0.925711, 0.378231, 0.000000, 0.000000);
ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
ctx.lineJoin = 'bevel';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 182, 1.0)';
ctx.lineCap = 'square';
ctx.miterLimit = 4;
ctx.lineWidth = 1.454460;
ctx.moveTo(96.909194, 181.195010);
ctx.translate(44.493169, 125.426997);
ctx.rotate(0.000000);
ctx.scale(0.857649, 1.000000);
ctx.arc(0.000000, 0.000000, 82.735886, 0.739676, 1.97531687, 0);
ctx.scale(1.165978, 1.000000);
ctx.rotate(-0.000000);
ctx.translate(-44.493169, -125.426997);
ctx.translate(44.493169, 125.426997);
ctx.rotate(0.000000);
ctx.scale(0.857649, 1.000000);
ctx.arc(0.000000, 0.000000, 82.735886, 1.975317, 3.21095758, 0);
ctx.scale(1.165978, 1.000000);
ctx.rotate(-0.000000);
ctx.translate(-44.493169, -125.426997);
ctx.translate(44.493168, 125.427002);
ctx.rotate(0.000000);
ctx.scale(0.857649, 1.000000);
ctx.arc(0.000000, 0.000000, 82.735886, -3.072228, -1.83658681, 0);
ctx.scale(1.165978, 1.000000);
ctx.rotate(-0.000000);
ctx.translate(-44.493168, -125.427002);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.transform(0.698524, 0.715587, -0.925711, 0.378231, 0.000000, 0.000000);
ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
ctx.lineJoin = 'bevel';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 182, 1.0)';
ctx.lineCap = 'square';
ctx.miterLimit = 4;
ctx.lineWidth = 1.454460;
ctx.moveTo(314.174770, 46.726323);
ctx.translate(243.974979, 58.791809);
ctx.rotate(0.000000);
ctx.scale(0.857649, 1.000000);
ctx.arc(0.000000, 0.000000, 82.735886, -0.146353, 1.08248298, 0);
ctx.scale(1.165978, 1.000000);
ctx.rotate(-0.000000);
ctx.translate(-243.974979, -58.791809);
ctx.translate(243.974972, 58.791813);
ctx.rotate(0.000000);
ctx.scale(0.857649, 1.000000);
ctx.arc(0.000000, 0.000000, 82.735886, 1.082483, 2.31131912, 0);
ctx.scale(1.165978, 1.000000);
ctx.rotate(-0.000000);
ctx.translate(-243.974972, -58.791813);
ctx.translate(243.974971, 58.791812);
ctx.rotate(0.000000);
ctx.scale(0.857649, 1.000000);
ctx.arc(0.000000, 0.000000, 82.735886, 2.311319, 3.54015529, 0);
ctx.scale(1.165978, 1.000000);
ctx.rotate(-0.000000);
ctx.translate(-243.974971, -58.791812);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.transform(-0.583905, -0.811822, 0.811822, -0.583905, -136.964043, -136.374478);
ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
ctx.lineJoin = 'bevel';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)';
ctx.lineCap = 'square';
ctx.miterLimit = 4;
ctx.lineWidth = 0.280017;
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 205)';
ctx.moveTo(-222.249990, 28.636906);
ctx.lineTo(-244.496310, 29.385587);
ctx.lineTo(-234.021530, 9.745368);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();

ctx.save();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.transform(0.591390, 0.806386, -0.806386, 0.591390, 338.164508, 412.730352);
ctx.globalAlpha = 1.0;
ctx.lineJoin = 'bevel';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)';
ctx.lineCap = 'square';
ctx.miterLimit = 4;
ctx.lineWidth = 0.280017;
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 205)';
ctx.moveTo(-222.249990, 28.636906);
ctx.lineTo(-244.496310, 29.385587);
ctx.lineTo(-234.021530, 9.745368);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.restore();
ctx.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='210' height='297'></canvas>
```